# get Generic CRUD operation in EF

Tags: wcf, architecture, repository-pattern

Is there any way or design pattern can I use to get Generic CRUD operations?

Because   I’m working on n-tire application using EF in the data layer and I don’t want to use CRUD Functions in Every Entities.

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern, where you implement the repository as an interface and then a base class.  For instance:

`IRepository where T : class

   void Save(T entity )

   T FindById( T id )
   ....`

EntityFrameworkRepositoryBase : IRepository
    void Save( T entity )
    {
       // do EF specfic stuff
     }....

Then for a given entity you can create(or inject) a concrete repository:

`PersonRepository : EntityFrameworkRepositoryBase`

From there, simply call the PersonRepository to Save or Find Persons.